React createBrowserRouter paths not working when refreshing the page after deploying the app to GitHub
I made a React/Vite fitness website and used createBrowserRouter to create all the paths, everything worked perfectly fine until I deployed the website to GitHub pages. An issue occurred:
Each time I refresh the page when I'm on a path that is not the home page, the browser redirects me to an error message from GitHub saying that there is no such file:

404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

https://shlcomp.github.io/youFitness2005/
Here is my code.
App.jsx:
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home/Home.jsx';
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShopAll from './pages/shopAll/ShopAll.jsx';
import ShopCats from './pages/shopCats/ShopCats.jsx';
import Filter from './components/filter/Filter.jsx';
import Error from './components/error/Error.jsx';
import Cart from './pages/cart/Cart.jsx';
import Provider from './context/Context.jsx';



const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: 'youFitness2005/',
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <Error />
  },
  {
    path: '/womens',
    element: <ShopCats category= "womens" />
  },
  {
    path: '/mens',
    element: <ShopCats category= "mens" />
  },
  {
    path: '/kids',
    element: <ShopCats category= "kids" />
  },
  {
    path: '/shopAll',
    element: <ShopAll />
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:productId',
    element: <Filter /> //will display the productDisplay, filtered by id
  },
  {
    path: '/cart',
    element: <Cart />
  }
]);
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Provider basename={"youFitness2005/"}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
    </>
  )
};

export default App;


Here's the Home page:
import Footer from "../../components/footer/Footer"
import Hero from "../../components/hero/Hero"
import Insp from "../../components/insp/Insp"
import Mazaya from "../../components/mazaya/Mazaya"
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar"

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />  
      <Hero />
      <Insp />
      <Mazaya />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home


Here's the Navbar.jsx page:
import './Navbar.scss';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { myContext } from '../../context/Context.jsx';

const Navbar = () => {
  const {openBurg} = useContext(myContext);
  //for a dynamic cartCount
  const {basket} = useContext(myContext); 
  //I was stupidly stuck with an error just cuz i imported basket with [] not {} :)
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  //updating the cartCount dynamically
  useEffect(()=>{
    const count = basket.map((item)=> item.quantity).reduce((x, y)=> x+y, 0);
    setCartCount(count);
  }, [basket]); //recalculate the basket updates


  return (
    <div>
      <section className="header">
        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul>






              //here are the paths: 



              <div className="main-navs">
                {/* make sure to link the home page to "/home-url" not "home-url/" */}
                <Link to="/youFitness2005"><img className="nav-icons logo-image" src={logo}/></Link>
                <i id='burg' className="fa-solid fa-bars" onClick={()=>openBurg()}></i>
              </div>
                <Link to="/youFitness2005" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">Home</li></Link>
                <Link to="/womens" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">Women&apos;s</li></Link>
                <Link to="/mens" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">Men&apos;s</li></Link>
                <Link to="/kids" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">Kid&apos;s</li></Link>
                <Link to="/shopAll" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">All Categories</li></Link>
                <Link to="/contact" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">Contact Us</li></Link>
                <Link to="/about" className='a'><li className="nav-icons">About Us</li></Link>
            </ul>
            
            
          
        <div className="other-uls">
        <ul>
            <li className="link"><i className="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></li>
            <Link to="/cart" className='a'><li className="link"  ><i id="cartCount" className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bag-shopping">({cartCount})</i></li></Link>
          
        </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

        
    </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar


Here are some other files (I'm not sure whether they are important to mention or not),
Package.json:
{
  "homepage": "https://SHLcomp.github.io/youFitness2005/",
  "name": "fitness",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "sass": "^1.80.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "gh-pages": "^6.2.0",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.10"
  }
}


vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/youFitness2005/"
})


Please help me fix this issue.
Thank you.

When using react-router to create a single page app (SPA), you usually have to make a change to the server to make it serve the files correctly. Otherwise the server will try to respond with a file that matches your literal sub route address instead of your main index file. Hence the 404.
Github pages is a bit limited for the configuration of SPA page apps, but it looks like some people have found some workarounds including modifying the 404 template file.
See this page for some example configurations when setting up your app: page not found - react/vite app not routing correctly on github pages
You can also reference this repo as an example SPA: https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages
